# What's the primary body entrance + surface of infection for catching the flu?

Tags: blood, infection, immune-system, prevention, lungs

I realize there are multiple ways, but if you tallied up all the people who caught the flu or a cold last year, what would be the majority...

- Entrance for infection:

  - Mouth
  - Nose
  - Eyes
  - Ears
  - Skin
- Bio surface that facilitates transmission:

  - Mouth walls/palate/tongue
  - Nose walls, cavity, sinuses
  - Eye surface
  - Throat walls
  - Lung tissue
  - Stomach/digestive tract surfaces

Again, I realize it's not just one entrance or surface that does the trick, I'm only wondering about the majorities.

Comment: I'm not sure how someone would collect those stats, but what has your research revealed so far?

Comment: The common entrance for certain infections are "mucous membranes," so mouth, nose and eyes, and may or may not include genitourinary tract. Intact skin and ears are not common entrances. Try to support your hypotheses with a linked source. These terms can help you in search: "portal of entry" and "transmission."

Comment: @CareyGregory So far, I've gathered it's the eyes, given they're a soft mucous membrane, but one which doesn't contain enzymes found in saliva/mucous that can break down cell walls of certain bacteria. Further, they're front-facing and constantly exposed to the air + any particles whisking about. But most of all, people apparently have a tendency to touch their faces on average 3000 times per day, and of those times, it's usually the eyes that are being touched or rubbed with our hands which function as the sieves that net particles of infection strewn about.

Comment: @Jan Thanks for the terms, Jan, those are helpful. Working on it now.

Comment: @Coldblackice Right, the eyes are one point of entry, but that doesn't answer my question to you. Imagine you're a doctor participating in a clinical trial and a patient comes into your office with the flu. How would you determine how that patient caught the flu? What was the point of entry? How could you possibly know?